# Racket - creating a floor function under certain constraints

Tags: scheme, racket, htdp

I'm quite stuck on trying to create a floor function with the following constraints:

I'm only allowed to use the following functions in section 1.5 of this page: http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html.

However you're not allowed to use the floor, round, ceiling and sgn function. In addition to all this, you are unable to use recursion, cond, lists or even helper functions.

Note: use only beginner student documentation

Comment: quotient only takes two integers as it's parameters. Not real numbers.

Comment: "Unable to use recursion"? This sounds like one interesting Scheme class...

Comment: It's so many constraints right now that I'm almost certain it's not doable. I can't wait to see what answer you post to your own question after your class.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a hint to get you started:

```
floor(x) = 0            if 0 <=x < 1
floor(x) = 1+floor(x-1) if x>1
```

In Scheme notation:

```
(define (myfloor x)
  (cond
    [(below-one? x)  0]
    [else           (add-one (myfloor (subtract-one x)))]))
```

All you need to do, is to figure out how to write `below-one` and `subtract-one`.

Comment: He wrote "unable to use recursion".

Comment: Then he will need to rewrite it to use an explicit stack :-)

Comment: The thing is that `modulo` only accepts integer arguments in Scheme and Racket. In Common Lisp, it's as easy as `(- n (mod n 1))`.

Comment: No lists! What is this nonsense.

Comment: Well, `vector` is provided by ASL and not specifically prohibited. ;)  Even if it weren't, one could roll their own `kcons` et al ala SICP. Just saying....